# Elegant way to increment a mongoose number field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What is the most elegant way to increment a mongoose number's field ?

```
var Book = new Schema({
   name: String,
   total: Number
})
```

How do i increment it in the API?

```
var book = new Book({
   name: req.body.name,
   total: ?
});

book.save(callback);
```

Comment: How can you increment a total if you are creating a new `Book`? Shouldn't your total always start at 1?

Answer (score 3):

You could write a mongoose plugin that intercepts save calls and returns the current counter from a counter collection.

The mongoose plugin

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = function(schema, options) {
    var options = options || {};
    options.name = options.name || 'generic';
    options.field = options.field || 'counter';

    var counterSchema = new Schema({ name : String, counter : Number });
    var CounterModel = mongoose.model('counters', counterSchema);

    schema.pre('save', function (next) {
        if (!this.isNew) {
            return next();
        }

        var self = this;

        CounterModel.findOneAndUpdate(
            { name : options.name }, 
            { 
                $inc : { counter : 1 }
            },
            { upsert : true }, function(err, counter) {
                if (err) { return next(err) };

                self.set(options.field, counter.counter);

                next();
        });
    });
}
```

This plugin is aware to keep multiple named counters in a collection named `counters`.

Using the mongoose plugin

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var counter = require('./plugin');

var TestSchema = new Schema({ counter : Number });
TestSchema.plugin(counter, { name : 'tests', counter : 'counter' });

var TestModel = mongoose.model('tests', TestSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost', function(err) {
    TestModel.create({}, function(err, test) {
        console.log(err, test);

        test.save(function(err, test) {
            console.log(err, test);
        });
    }); 
});
```